# MySQL Merge Index Optimization not working

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I was try simulate merge index on MySQL like say here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/index-merge-optimization.html but i have no ideea why i dont take column type = 'index merge'.

Here i have contruction table:

```
    create table hotel(
 index1 int not null,
  nume varchar(100),
  index2 int
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX hotel_index1 ON hotel (index1);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX hotel_index2 ON hotel (index2);

insert into hotel(index1,nume,index2) values (1,'primu',1),
(2,'al2lea',2),(5,'al3lea',4),(4,'al4lea',5);
```

and i do select like say on site :

```
explain extended select * from hotel where index1 = 5 or index2 = 4;
```

and the result row from explain is:

```
    id  select_type table   type    possible_keys                key         key_len    ref     rows    filtered    Extra
    1   SIMPLE      hotel   const   hotel_index1,hotel_index2   (null)      (null)      (null)  4        100        Using where
```

What i do wrong with index and they do not merge like in theroy ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answar for that i don't see merge index optimization is because this apply if i use `limit` because then MySQL will divide `or` group and will try find best index and do search , and in the end he union all result.

```
explain extended select * from hotel where index1 = 5 OR index2 = 4 limit 3;
```

I get good answer:

```
    id  select_type table   type        possible_keys                key                         key_len    ref         rows     filtered   Extra
    1   SIMPLE      hotel   index_merge hotel_index1,hotel_index2    hotel_index1,hotel_index2   4,5        (null)      2        100        Using union(hotel_index1,hotel_index2); Using where
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL optimizers are really bad at `or` optimizations.  An alternative is to use `union` or `union all`.  The exact equivalent is:

```
select h.*
from hotel h
where h.index1 = 5 
union
select h.*
from hotel h
where index2 = 4;
```

This should use the indexes correctly (assuming the tables are large enough to take advantage of an index).

Note:  this uses `union`.  If you don't need the elimination of duplicates, then use `union all`.

EDIT:

The [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index-merge-optimization.html) has this insightful comment:

> The choice between different possible variants of the Index Merge
>   access method and other access methods is based on cost estimates of
>   various available options.

Apparently, the cost estimates don't lead the optimizer to the optimal choice.

Comment: yes but me ask this because mysql have a merge optimization and he use it if you use "or" between 2 or more indexs, and he do exactly what you say but, in explain query i must see value from column type='index merge' but i don;t see this , i see "all", for that i ask because i don't see it and i want to know if realy work.

Comment: There's another thing coming into play.  You have 4 rows in the table.  And you were asking for 2 of them.  That is 50%.  With such a high percentage, it is more efficient to scan the table instead of the complexity of using the indexes (or even one index).  That is, it was actually an optimization to do ALL instead of index_merge!

Comment: What version are you using?  5.7 improves the cost model.